# pjax -- must links be inside the pjax-container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pjax

I am using https://github.com/rails/pjax_rails.

I want to have my links inside a "permanent" portion of the page.  I.e. in my layout I have

```
<%= link_to "Some Action", some_action_path %>
```

Then inside the view:

```
<div data-pjax-container>Content to be replaced</div>
```

Here is my javascript where I invoke pjax:

```
('[data-pjax-container]').pjax('a');
```

[You may note that this is different than the invocation method in the readme, but as a reported issue points out, the method in the readme doesn't work at all.]

This is not working (the link reloads the entire page).

If I move the link inside the div with the data-pjax-container attribute, it works (the page is not reloaded and only the container is updated).

I have not seen any examples where the link was actually outside of the container.  Can anyone tell me how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was probably focusing too much on the pjax-rails readme (not great).  I went to the source (https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) which led me to changing my js to this:

```
$(document).pjax('a', '[data-pjax-container]')
```

..which got me back on the right track.

Comment: I made the same mistake of using someone else's js.  It's nice when documentation is actually useful.